# Angular Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'

Tags: angular

I have a service which gets json data from rest call (firebase) using GET request. I am trying to show the response data on middle-box.component.html

Any suggestions or solutions to fix this error:

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

twitter.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class TwitterService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {}
  getJobs() {
    var jobs = {}
    console.log('Twitter Service Called !');
    return this.http.get('https://dmm-db.firebaseio.com/jobs.json')
    .map(
        (response: Response) => {
          var data = response.json();
          var jobs = [], item;

          for (var type in data) {
            console.log(type);
              item = {};
              item.name = type;
              jobs.push(item);
          }
          console.log(jobs);
          return jobs;
        }

      )
  }
}
```

middle-box.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-middle-box',
    templateUrl: './middle-box.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./middle-box.component.css']
})

export class MiddleBoxComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private twitterService: TwitterService) {
    twitterService.getJobs()
      .subscribe(
        (jobs: any[]) => this.jobs = jobs,
        (error) => console.log('Error: '+ error),
        () => console.log('Completed')
      );
  }
```

middle-box.component.html

```
<ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let job of jobs">
  <li class="list-group-item">{{ job.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: BTW, I have read other solutions and tried few things, none of it worked. and also I am newbie in angular, so spare me if I am missing basic constructs here. But I do need help, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try these

```
export class MiddleBoxComponent implements OnInit {

  private jobs: any[];
  private isLoading: boolean = false;

  constructor(private twitterService: TwitterService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.twitterService.getJobs()
      .subscribe((jobs: any[]) => {
          this.jobs = jobs,
          this.isLoading = false;
      },
        (error: any[]) => console.log('Error: ' + error),
        () => console.log('Completed')
      );
  }
```

use ngOnInit() to call your APIs instead of constructor. that is a good practice.

```
  <ul class="list-group" *ngIf="!isLoading" *ngFor="let job of jobs" >
  <li class="list-group-item" > {{ job.name }}</li>
    < /ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

jobs, is not defined in your component but within your twitter service.

You need twitterservice to access jobs from middle-box.component.ts in order to use it in your html.

so you can assign it to a local jobs, or use twitterservice.jobs.name

Answer (score 0):

This is a answer coming from a newby, so take it with a grain of salt. I had this issue also, but when I used the async method and did not bother with a subscription the issue went away.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-middle-box',
    templateUrl: './middle-box.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./middle-box.component.css']
})

export class MiddleBoxComponent implements OnInit {
  public jobs; 

  constructor(private twitterService: TwitterService) {
    this.jobs = twitterService.getJobs();
  }
```

---

```
<ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let job of jobs | async">
  <li class="list-group-item">{{ job.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

**Note**: In Angular 5, you no longer call the .json on the response in the observable(no `var data = response.json()`).